# Editing duplicated layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile called 'Roads' with on the fly CRS which is ok but not for what I want to achieve. I already know the correct CRS value I want to essential duplicate the Road shapefile with the correct CRS and then continue editing the new shapefile. I have currently duplicated the road shapefile changed the CRS value and then tried to re-save it but once I do that and then try to open it again QGIS 3 comes up with an error message

I need a step by step guide as I am clearly missing something.

Comment: What is the error message?  What are the precise and detailed steps that you perform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it the following:

1. Load your original 'Roads' Shapefile into QGIS
2. Save this Layer as new file. While saving it, choose the CRS you wish it to have. [image]
3. Load this newly saved Shapefile into QGIS
4. Edit this new Shapefile

Why:

- Duplicating a layer in QGIS does not create a real duplicate. It is actually just loaded twice.
- Setting the CRS of a layer does not reproject it. You need to save it as new file to reproject it. Make sure it has the correct original CRS assigned before saving it with the new CRS.